# Massive data in Laravel list

Tags: php, html, laravel

To create an article I need to chose the name of the author from a listbox and I realised that more I have authors the list getting hard to chose from.
The data is retrieved from my database table, any idea how can i make pages on my list? I means page 1 show maybe 10 authors and the second will show the next 10 something like this that can help me display it on a better way? 
This is my code, and it's working:

```
 <select required class="form-control" name="client_id" style="width:90%"  >

          @foreach($clients as $client)
          <center>
            <option  class="form-control" value= "{{ $client->id}}" >{{ $client->num_mowakil }} | {{$client->nom_mowakil}}</option>
          </center>
          @endforeach
        </select>
```

Comment: Have you considered some sort of search, via something like [typeahead.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smart-search-with-laravel-and-typeahead-js)?

Comment: sorry I have no idea what is typehead.js I have tryed to create autocomplete input that bring the data from my database but everytime I followed a tutorial it's not working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Laravel has a neat built-in pagination generator for you.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Edit:
If you want to keep the current form data you have I recommend having a look at [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

For example, when the form input changes using jQuery

```
$( yourInputId ).change(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('myInput', this.val());
});
```

And then when the document loads

```
$( yourInputId).val(localStorage.getItem('myInput'))
```

Comment: Pagination will work on a select box as the same way as it work for table?

Comment: @MehdiElAissi Yes

Comment: @AidenKaiser What? No, it won't. A `<select>` won't have any idea what to do with paginated data.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes it will, it will only show the data for the page you are currently on

Comment: @AidenKaiser When you click into the next page for the `<select>`'s options, the *rest* of your form data will be all gone.

Comment: @ceejayoz That is what he was asking.

Comment: @AidenKaiser Imagine the form with this `<select>` also has a `<textarea>` where you just spent 45 minutes writing an article. When you click the second page on the `<select>`'s paginator, the whole page will reload and OP'll lose their 45 minutes of work. You'd need some sort of AJAX solution in place so *only* the `<select>` changs.

Comment: But as @ceejayoz said it's making my form all empty any idea how to fix this guys? Or any alternative for the list ? I was looking all the day for input with autocomplete but I find it kind of hard to make it work

Comment: @MehdiElAissi In your controller, have a source for the paginated table (source 1) and a source for the form (source 2)

Comment: @AidenKaiser You're still not getting it. OP has a **form**. The user will have entered **other data**. Any click on the paginator to go to a different page will *reload* that form, losing all the other entered data. A paginator is not a feasible solution for a `<select>` in a form for this reason, unless you do other work around it (i.e. AJAXifying it).

Comment: It's a creation form it's empty already all inputs are empty the only empty that load with data is the select box.

Comment: Ok thanks im trying it and keep to dig for a solution